PORT number and the deep confusion
I am new to Networking and going through the theory. Kindly help me on following query :

So i came across port number which says that through this OS of node at which the packet is received will come to know about the application/process/service to which this packet data belongs and forward it suitably.

If we deep dive and take example of server side, then actually a socket is requested by application/S/w/process/Service which is then created by OS and that particular socket is communication endpoint for that application/S/w/process/Service. That socket is actually configured to listen a traffic at particular and hence you client must sent a request specifying the right port.


So far theory is clear

Then i read about ARP protocol and observed that ARP datagram is encapsulated in Ethernet frame. ARP message doesn't have any port number information.
Answer i got says that it's because ARP request are not handled by any software application on a node, its actually handled by OS networking stack and hence data received in ARP packet is used internally is OS and not forwarded to any application or service.
So it doesn't need a port number.

Now Port number is only needed when data in packet need to be forwarded to some application on the node.


Is it a correct understanding ??


Then i read about ARP protocol and observed that ARP datagram is encapsulated in Ethernet frame. ARP message doesn't have any port number information. Answer i got says that it's because ARP request are not handled by any software application on a node, its actually handled by OS networking stack and hence data received in ARP packet is used internally is OS and not forwarded to any application or service. So it doesn't need a port number.

Port numbers serve two purposes – to distinguish the higher protocol and to distinguish between multiple uses of that protocol (connections or sockets or flows).
For the first use, ARP packets do have something like that – ARP as a whole is recognized by the "Ethertype" field in the Ethernet header, which serves the same primary purpose of indicating "which part of the code" to allow handle the packet. There is an ethertype for IPv4, there is one for ARP, and there is one for IPv6.
(Some Ethernet frame formats use LLC/SNAP for the same purpose.)
Similarly, IP itself also has a "protocol" or "next header" field that indicates whether its payload is TCP or UDP or ICMP or GRE or something else (and you can likewise have some protocols handled by the OS, and some handled by applications that use raw sockets; notably OSPF).
For the second purpose, of distinguishing between multiple streams for the same protocol (which allows different programs to use the same remote port concurrently), ARP has no equivalent but it's also not needed; usually there indeed is only one ARP handler within the OS, and if other software wants to generate/listen on ARP packets, there's no harm in duplicating them, and the ARP responses are inherently easy to distinguish from each other (they always have the requested MAC in them).
(For comparison, ICMP Echo Request aka "ping" is recognized by the IP protocol number for 'ICMP' and multiple concurrent ping invocations are recognized by an ID field, altogether serving a similar purpose to e.g. UDP dest/source ports.)
The distinction between "internally by OS" and "an external application or service" doesn't really matter that much – you could easily have the OS making TCP connections all by itself, and it would still need the same things as an external application does.

Sockets can also be used to work with raw IP (generating packets with a custom IP protocol number, like an OSPF service might) and with raw Ethernet (generating frames with a custom ethertype, like an LLDP service might). They're an OS-specific concept though (a lot like "file handles"); it just so happens that most operating systems adopted the same "BSD socket" interface, but I've seen several different ways that programs could do networking before that.

Than you very much for your answer .
Its not allowing me to add my comment and in this reply only limited characters are allowed. so i have edited my question with adding reply to your comment at bottom with heading " Reply to comment by u1686_grawity (Apr 5).

Thankyou for your time in describing this.


I closely followed the Ether_type field in Ethernet II frame an how it indicates protocol according to which payload has to be processed. Ex 0X086 for ARP


Similarly i found Protocol field in IP packet which indicates similar thing about IP packet payload. Example : 0X0800 for ICMP.


I read about sockets as well, how server socket is configured to listen to a specific port and how client socket configured to send a connection request on a particular port.



after conceptually understanding these points sorry but it still confuses me :
when a protocol packet (Layer 3 and Layer 2) doesn't have port number in its frame/packet how it will be processed after received at receiver's NIC.
Only answer i got is it happens without any problem because these protocol task will be handled by OS networking stack only and not by any other application/process/service.
Because when a service/application needs some data from network it will request OS to create a socket.

I was not able to understand following lines
"The distinction between "internally by OS" and "an external application or service" doesn't really matter that much – you could easily have the OS making TCP connections all by itself"
Is it possible that you give me some questions and i will try to find answers to those questions which will help me to betters understand how OS and application interacts.
I think this will clarify my query also.
Thankyou again for your help with time and knowledge.

I think that needs to build on the understanding of how files are accessed (i.e. what "file handles" and/or "file descriptors" and/or "FCBs" are – how they keep state for an "open file", how the open/seek/read/close functions work in a program). Sockets are very similar to that, serving practically the same function (and indeed often  are a special type of file handles).

Ok Thanks, i'll go through these concepts.

ARP is the mechanism used by the high layer to recognize the address of the receiving device on the lower layer.
For example in an ethernet LAN, TCP/IP needs to send a packet to another device, then to put the packet in the wire it needs to know which is the MAC address of the receiving device.
ARP is used to ask using a broadcast something like : "What's the MAC address of W.X.Y.Z?"
If the device with IP address W.X.Y.Z exists and it is connected it will reply with it s MAC address, then the sender can start sending directly to that device.
ARP doesn't depend on a port because it is part of the TCP/IP Suite and it's essential to its functionality.
Ports are like doors. Imagine that for each packet coming if it is normal UDP or TCP, it comes with a destination port, then it is redirected to an internal "door" that opens the access to an specific application.

Thanks for you answer jcbermu
